# Navbar is not showing the list item

Tags: sveltekit

I am using svelte kit and I used flowbite-svelte to make the navbar but the problem that navbar is not working in big screen and not showing the list item.

```
<script>
  import { Navbar, NavBrand, NavLi, NavUl, NavHamburger } from 'flowbite-svelte'
</script>

<Navbar let:hidden let:toggle>
  <NavBrand href="/">
    <span class="self-center whitespace-nowrap text-xl font-semibold dark:text-white">
      Flowbite
    </span>
  </NavBrand>
  <NavHamburger on:click={toggle} />
  <NavUl {hidden}>
    <NavLi href="/" active={true}>Home</NavLi>
    <NavLi href="/about">About</NavLi>
    <NavLi href="/services">Services</NavLi>
    <NavLi href="/pricing">Pricing</NavLi>
    <NavLi href="/contact">Contact</NavLi>
  </NavUl>
</Navbar>
```

I want the list to be shown on big screen

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow all parts of the [quickstart instructions](https://flowbite-svelte.com/docs/pages/quickstart).

If the menu is not showing up, the CSS is probably not being generated correctly, probably the respective entries for the `flowbite-svelte` styles and plugin are missing from the `tailwind.config.cjs` (see [this step](https://flowbite-svelte.com/docs/pages/quickstart#Configuration)).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem before , I fixed the bug by importing the flowbite styles in the style html tag in my svelte component

`<!-- MyComponent.svelte -->`

This is the code with the import statement in "style html element":
[image: This is the code with the import statement in "style html element"]

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I messed with my tailwind.config.cjs file, it seems there are some things that you must not change if you want flowbite to work. In my tailwind.config.cjs I added

```
screens: {
    'sm': '360'
}
```

and flowbite stopped working. Check if you've changed anything in your tailwind.config.cjs and changed it back.