# Svelte flowbite NavBar Display Issue

Tags: sveltekit, flowbite-svelte

I just started using Flowbite with Svelete.  I followed the instructions located in
the following [link](https://flowbite-svelte.com/docs/pages/quickstart), and the sample works as expected.  But in a new +layout.svelte, I added a NavBar, which I copied exactly like the [sample](https://flowbite-svelte.com/docs/components/navbar).

[image]

But when I view the page, no matter the browser width, it always showing in a mobile view

[image]

This was [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76788212/navbar-is-not-showing-the-list-item) previously but had no solution.  Any ideas on what I may be missing?

My tailwind.config.js

```
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
    const config = {
      content: [
        './src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}', 
        './node_modules/flowbite-svelte/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}'
      ],
      theme: {
        extend: {
                colors: {
                    primary: {
                        50: '#FFF5F2',
                        100: '#FFF1EE',
                        200: '#FFE4DE',
                        300: '#FFD5CC',
                        400: '#FFBCAD',
                        500: '#FE795D',
                        600: '#EF562F',
                        700: '#EB4F27',
                        800: '#CC4522',
                        900: '#A5371B'
                      }             
                }

        },
        screens: {
          mobile: { max: "480px" },
          tablet: { min: "481px", max: "1024px" },
          desktop: { min: "1025px" }
        }
      },
      plugins: [
        require('flow bite/plugin')
      ],
      darkMode: 'class'
    }

    module.exports = config;
```

**Update Solution**

Nevermind, I needed to add the following media query in my tailwind.config.js file.

```
screens: {
  'sm': '640px',
  // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }

  'md': '768px',
  // => @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

  'lg': '1024px',
  // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }

  'xl': '1280px',
  // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }

  '2xl': '1536px',
  // => @media (min-width: 1536px) { ... }
}
```

Found the information [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens).

Answer (score 0):

I updated my question with the solution that fixed my problem.  The [media query](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens) was missing in the tailwind.config.js file.  Now its working as expected.